# Can I keep Vuejs event in HTML data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I would like to keep Vue event working with response html data.

1/Description:

- In `<template><div id="id_1" v-on:click="method(value)">TEXT</div></template>` : It work when I click this.
- Now when I have html data replace content in id_1, for example:

  `var data = "<div id='id_1'>TEXT 2</div>";
  $('#id_1').html(data );`

My code follow: axios -> socket.on -> append or html with event like above.

2/ Problem: I can not put v-on:click into data like this:

`<div v-on:click="method(value)" id='id_1'>TEXT 2</div>` .

3/ Alternatives so far :I have to make different function in Jquery. It's mean two way in one vue file. It work in this way. Is there any way to put vue event in data like above ?

Thanks in advance,
Quang Tran

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to replace the whole HTML.
Just make a model like :

```
data() {
  return {
    text: ''
  }
}
```

And then in mounted state or else depends on your situation:

```
mounted() {
  let vm = this;
  vm.text = 'test123';
}
```

In your HTML use this:

```
<template><div id="id_1" v-on:click="method(value)">{{text}}</div></template>
```

Hope it will helps you :)

Comment: Thank you,Indra. You mean if I want to append/html new data , thus do code `this.text="new_data"`, right ?

It work but I put it in socket.on, so add new data by Vuejs way does not work. I still don't know reason and keep try to find out.

Comment: I never work with Socket.IO. Usually I get the data just using axios and render html based on the data.
You probably need this rerender API provided by Vue https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate

Comment: got it, I will try it